# Как группировать в cxGrid при gridmode:=true без сортировки?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, vcl

На формуме DevExpress написано, что вроде нельзя.
Но вчера у меня почему-то получалось. То есть ставил `groupindex:=0` по колонке 
`GridMode:=true`, а сама колонка шла **не** сортированная: таблица

```
AAAA
AAAA
BBBB
BBBB
AAAA
AAAA
```

превращалась в

```
AAAA+
BBBB+
AAAA+
```

А сегодня не могу повторить.

Comment: Фаза луны уже сменилась, и подозреваю что Марс уже не в том доме ;)

Comment: причем в конференциях на девках этот вопрос много раз подымался и решения разработчики пока не нашли